# How to find the radio button selected when I have the containing div

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html:

```
    <input type="text" class="searchpersontxtbox" />
    <input type="button" value="Find" class="findpersonbtn btn" disabled="disabled" />
    <img class="loader" style="display: none;" alt="Loading..." src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif")" />
    <div class="peopleresultsdiv"></div>
    <div class="contactType">
        <input type="radio" name="searchtype" value="person" >Person
        <input type="radio" name="searchtype" value="organisation" checked="checked">Organisation
    </div>
<input type="text" class="searchpersontxtbox" />
    <input type="button" value="Find" class="findpersonbtn btn" disabled="disabled" />
    <img class="loader" style="display: none;" alt="Loading..." src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif")" />
    <div class="peopleresultsdiv"></div>
    <div class="contactType">
        <input type="radio" name="searchtype" value="person" checked="checked">Person
        <input type="radio" name="searchtype" value="organisation">Organisation
    </div>
```

So there are two searches here. What I'm wanting to know is when the find button is clicked how do I determine which radio button was clicked? So if the find button was clicked on the first it would be organisation and if the find button was click on the second search it would be person.

I think I could work out how to do this if there was only one search on the page but the fact that there is two is confusing me.

Comment: Shouldn't you change the name of the second group?

Comment: `contactType` id is repeated what is illegal and I agree that you should have different names for radio buttons groups. Is it possible for you to work on these two issues first?

Comment: your html looks so confusing. why did you copy and paste the same content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine the index of the clicked button and then access the radio group with the same index, using JQuery:

```
$('input[type=button]').index($this)
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/hd72Q/

Answer (score 0):

If these are different searches then IMHO you need to change names of radio input types in each group otherwise they act like one group. So for a second search it might be

```
<input type="radio" name="searchtype2" value="person" checked="checked">Person
<input type="radio" name="searchtype2" value="organisation">Organisation
                                    ^
```

And this is another way to get a value of a checked radio input type that relates to your find button

```
$(".findpersonbtn.btn").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).nextAll(".contactType").first().find("input[type=radio]:checked").val();
    alert(value);
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/JeSmd/)**